# How to write a Snowflake SELECT statement query in Advance Editor from powerBi

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to repoint the data Source of a power Bi dashboard from SQL to Snowflake.

So far, for most of the tables worked. However, I got one table on which I got the following error when changing the data source:

> ***Expression.Error: 'Query' are not valid Snowflake options. Valid options are: 'ConnectionTimeout, CommandTimeout, CreateNavigationProperties, Role'***

This specific query ( from Advance Editor in PowerBi) contains a simple select and it looks as follows:

```
let
    Source =Snowflake.Databases("serverabc", "abc", [Query="SELECT DateLabel, SnapshotDate, Future, Latest#(lf)FROM Xtable#(lf)WHERE DateLabel IS NOT NULL#(lf)GROUP BY DateLabel, SnapshotDate, Future, Latest", CreateNavigationProperties=false]),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each true)
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

The select statement works in both SQL and Snowflake but I am having difficulties on how to translate this in Power BI as well.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Thanks so much,Lukasz, for the insight. I've brought the table in pbi and I've adapted the select statement in M code. It worked!

Comment: Great to hear it. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) The updated connector (June 2021) now allows to pefrom custom query. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

[PowerBI June](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-june-2021-feature-summary)

> **Snowflake (updated connector)**
>
> **We are adding the highly demanded Custom SQL support for the Snowflake connector.** Like the SQL connector, this will let you input a Snowflake native query and then build reports on top of it. This will work with both Import and Direct Query mode.

https://powerbiblogscdn.azureedge.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/snowflake_update.png

---

> Expression.Error: 'Query' are not valid Snowflake options. Valid options are: 'ConnectionTimeout, CommandTimeout, CreateNavigationProperties, Role'

It seems that the previous source was supporting "custom query".

> [Sql.Database](https://www.powerquery.io/accessing-data/sql/sql.database)
>
> ```
> function (server as text, database as text, optional options as nullable record) as table
> ```
>
> Query : A native SQL query used to retrieve data. If the query produces multiple result sets, only the first will be returned.

---

PowerBI connector to Snowflake does not support such option:

> [Snowflake.Databases](https://www.powerquery.io/accessing-data/snowflake/snowflake.databases)
>
> ```
> function (server as text, warehouse as text, optional options as nullable record) as table
> ```
>
> options, may be specified to control the following options:
>
> - ConnectionTimeout: The number of seconds to wait for network responses from Snowflake.
> - CommandTimeout: The number of seconds to wait for a query to execute.

There is active ticket: [Snowflake connector -> add SQL statement as optional](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=25342316-0a28-401e-a6ad-9d7740a5dce8).

---

Possible workarounds:

1. Create a view in Snowflake that wraps the query and use it instead
2. Access the table content and perform the filtering/aggregation in
   PowerQuery